# C Strings storing values into array without over writting

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, null

I am trying to get the last 10 commands entered in my program. The issue I am having is that I take arguments from the command line and store that into my array but I keep over writing the values in my array because they are storing a pointer not an actual character array value. I want to know how to take the current character array (going to be changing with each command entered) and store that value into an array. I know its a pointer issue but I'm unsure of how to fix this

My code is below. my char array history[] goes as follows with the following input:

input a
history[0] = a
input b
history[0] = b history[1] = b
input c
history[0] = c history[1] = c history[2] = c

```
#define MAX 256
#define CMD_MAX 10
#define HISTORY_MAX 10

int make_history(char *history[], int history_counter, char *input_line)
{
  if(history_counter < HISTORY_MAX)
  {
    history[history_counter] = input_line;
  }
  return 1;
}



int make_tokenlist(char *buf, char *tokens[])
{
   char input_line[MAX];
   char *line;
   int i,n;

   i = 0;
   line = buf;
   tokens[i] = strtok(line, " ");

   do
   {
    i++;
    line = NULL;
    tokens[i] = strtok(line, " ");
   }

   while(tokens[i] != NULL);

   return i;
 }

int main()
{
  char input_line[MAX], *tokens[CMD_MAX], *history[HISTORY_MAX];
  int i, n, history_counter;

  while(1)
  {
    printf("abc> ");

    if (gets(input_line) != NULL)
    {
     n= make_tokenlist(input_line, tokens);
    }
    else
    {
     printf("error?");
     return 1;
    }

    make_history(history,history_counter,input_line);

    if(strcmp(tokens[0],"history")==0)
    {
     for (i = 0; i < HISTORY_MAX; i++)
     {
       if(history[i]!=NULL)
       {
         printf("%d. %s \n", i, history[i]);
       }
     }
    } 

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
     printf("extracted token is %s\n", tokens[i]);
    }

    history_counter++; //increment history counter
  }
}
```

Comment: have you looked into using a library for this? something like the readline library? http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/rlman_2.html

Comment: you don't allocate memory for 10*256 char at all, use 2d array or malloc and free

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem (which I think you understand) is that you're storing a pointer to the same character array as `input_line`. In other words, the string inside `history` and input_line are the same data.

The solution is to make a copy of the `input_line` and storing *that* into the `history`. A naïve implementation (which **will not work**) is as follows:

```
int make_history(char *history[], int history_counter, char *input_line)
{
    if(history_counter < HISTORY_MAX)
    {
        char input_copy[MAX];
        strcpy(input_copy, input_line);
        history[history_counter] = input_copy;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Now, you're making a copy of the line into memory that *isn't* used anywhere else (`input_copy`). That should work, right? The problem is that declaring a variable like that (called static allocation) stores the variable's data on the stack. When a function returns, all the data that was put in the stack by that function is destroyed. When `make_history()` returns, `input_copy` is destroyed, and since `history[history_counter]` was pointing to the same array as `input_copy`, it's now pointing to a bit of memory that's probably going to be used for other purposes by the program and won't contain your copy of the input line any more.

You can use *dynamic allocation* to get around the issue of statically allocated memory existing only in the scope it is declared in. `malloc()` allocates memory on what's called the *heap* (in C; in C++ you'd use `new`). Data in the heap doesn't get destroyed while the program is running unless you tell it to free the memory yourself. Example:

```
int make_history(char *history[], int history_counter, char *input_line)
{
    if(history_counter < HISTORY_MAX)
    {
        char *input_copy = (char *)malloc(MAX * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(input_copy, input_line);
        history[history_counter] = input_copy;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This will work, since data in the heap (allocated by `malloc()`) will survive after `make_history()` returns and until either you free that memory yourself, or the program ends. Note how I use `sizeof(char)`—this is because primitive types (e.g. `int`, `char`) can differ in size according to the kind of processor you're compiling for, the compiler you're using, etc. (**EDIT:** Just a note, `sizeof(char) == 1` is defined by the C specification (I think all revisions), and all other data type sizes are given in multiples of `char`.)

But what if:

```
// history_counter == 0
make_history(history,history_counter,input_line);
// ...
// later, when history_counter == 0 again somehow
make_history(history, history_counter, another_input_line);
```

All the second `make_history()` did was change a pointer from the copy of `input_line` to the copy of another_input_line! It never frees the memory of the first `input_line`, and now all the pointers to it have disappeared. That's called a memory leak (and it would be wonderful if they were all that simple!). If this were possible in your program (say, you made `history_counter` loop back to 0), you would want to fix this. After you allocated that memory the first time, you can just reuse it, right?

```
int make_history(char *history[], int history_counter, char *input_line)
{
    if(history_counter < HISTORY_MAX)
    {
        if(history[history_counter] == NULL)
        {
            history[history_counter] = (char *)malloc(MAX * sizeof(char));
        }
        strcpy(history[history_counter], input_line);
        history[history_counter] = input_copy;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Now you're checking if you had already stored a copy of a line in `history[history_counter]` before, and if not you `malloc()` the memory first. Either way, after that you copy `input_line` into the `history` array. (There's another problem with your code that will break this; see below.)

Another thing you should know about dynamic allocation, since that seems to be the subject we're on, is that to free memory that you allocated using `malloc()`, use `free()`. For C++, to free memory allocated using `new`, use `delete`.

---

Another possible solution, as mentioned by a comment to your question: you could statically allocate `10*256*sizeof(char)` bytes in `main()` right off the bat. It's a simpler solution, but uses up that memory all the time instead of just when needed. Your example is simple and doesn't require that much memory, but in bigger/more complicated programs, that difference can matter.

---

By the way, a few issues in your code other than the question:

You never initialize `history_counter` in `main()`, so its initial value is undefined when you call `make_history()`. You should treat an uninitialized variable (declared, but no value assigned) as random—in reality, the value depends on processor/system, compiler, OS, and is nothing you should rely on. Therefore, the second line of `main()` should be:

```
int i, n, history_counter = 0;
```

Similarly, you declared `history` as:

```
char *history[HISTORY_MAX];
```

and you don't initialize that array of pointers to `NULL` values. Later on you check:

```
if(history[i] != NULL)
```

but you have no guarantee that the default value of `history[i]` is `NULL` for all `i`. You should initialize the `history` array to all `NULL` values first. My last example above for my actual answer also relies on this initialization being done, and bad things could happen if you try to `free()` an unallocated address.